# Django Model DatetimeField without seconds

Tags: django, django-models

I want to enter date and time in my admin site  with

```
 date = models.DateTimeField()
```

But I dont want to have the seconds in my view. Is it possible to display the time like this:

10:45 instead of 10:45:00 ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield

> input_formats
>
> A list of formats used to attempt to convert a string to a valid datetime.datetime object.
>
> If no input_formats argument is provided, the default input formats are:

Thats if you want to save as well with no seconds, If you only want to change how its displayed in your templates your can use the **date** template filter:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Comment: thank you. But if I do so, I lose the buttons for now and the calendar. can it be managed in (models.Model)?

Comment: did you see the template filter? otherwise you could create a model method that returns the formated datetime value to your needs.